# Why does overriding putAt result in MissingPropertyException?

Tags: grails, groovy

I've been trying to take advantage of [operator overloading in Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading) by defining a custom `putAt` method in my POGO like this:

```
class Book {
    Map additionalInfo = [:]

    def putAt(key, value) {
        additionalInfo[key] = value
    }
}
```

So that I can do something like, `book['notes'] = 'I like this one.'` (let's say this makes sense). However, I've been getting:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: notes for class: Book
    at BookSpec.Set property using putAt(BookSpec.groovy:40)
```

My class is part of a Grails application so I'm not sure if Grails has something to do with the problem. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature should be

```
def putAt(String key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `putAt` and then override the operator, there is an easy/better way by adding the `propertyMissing` methods. 
Here is the [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing) for more explanation.

```
class Foo {
   def storage = [:]
   def propertyMissing(String name, value) { storage[name] = value }
   def propertyMissing(String name) { storage[name] }
}
def f = new Foo()
f.foo = "bar"

assertEquals "bar", f.foo
```